# circ package: multiple problems

Tags: metafont

I have multiple problems with circ package.

1. if I install from repository everything seems ok. However during compilation LaTeX says unknown METAFONT error or so.
2. Then I decided to compile fonts as explained in circ.pdf. However for 2 files I get error messages:

For a command "mf \mode=localfont; input csym.mf" I get the following message:

> ```
> This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (MiKTeX 2.9)
> (c:\Users\goldobin\Documents\t\circ\csym.mf)
> ! Emergency stop.
> <*> \mode=localfont; input csym.mf
> ```

For the command "mf \mode=localfont; input defcirc.mf" I get somethign even worse:

> ```
> This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (MiKTeX 2.9)
> (c:\Users\goldobin\Documents\t\circ\defcirc.mf
> CIRC %<*UNSPECIFIED>
> CIRC \freecirc
> CIRC \addCIRCfont UNSPECIFIED
> CIRC %</UNSPECIFIED>
> >> "CIRC %<+doc> \optionline "
> >> optionname
> ! Not implemented: (string)&(unknown numeric).
> <to be read again>
>                    )
> l.35 ...ge("CIRC %<+doc> \optionline "&optionname)
>                                                   ;
> >> optionname
> ! Not a string.
> <to be read again>
>                    ;
> l.35 ...e("CIRC %<+doc> \optionline "&optionname);
>
> CIRC %<*UNSPECIFIED,doc>
> )
> ! Emergency stop.
> <*> \mode=localfont; input defcirc.mf
> ```

3. Then my tex circ-code works in a strange way and sometimes does not work with messages like :

> ```
> ! Use of \- doesn't match its definition. 
> \iv* #1 #2 ->\cnta* =0\csname CiRC#2\endcsname
>                                               \relax \ifnum \cnta* =0 \Pack... 
> l.49   \-
>           1 r
> ```

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Please post the minimal code that leads to this error, not just the error log.

Comment: Maybe you can consider the more modern `tikz-circuit` package.